# Puffing up a logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

I am sure that it is possible for a designer software, however I do not know how it would be done!!! I want to change my logo

[image]

to make it embossed style for example as:

[image]

Can anyone guide or help me?

Comment: Hi. Sorry but I'm not sure what you mean by "protuberant (snaggy) style".  Do you mean embossed? Or perhaps add a drop shadow?  Also note that generally speaking, Photoshop is not ideal for logo design.  Better to use a vector image editor, such as Illustrator or Inkscape.

Comment: Yes "embossed" is correct. I think  a drop shadow makes the second shape seems to be embossed. I edited my question to don't limit ourselves by just Photoshop.

Comment: Just duplicate the logo layer, fill the top layer with a colour (not black), then move the black layer underneath a few pixels to the left/right/up/down.  This should work in almost any graphic design software.

Comment: I am really ashamed to make this request of you, but if it doesn't take much of your time, and it is possible, can you do it and upload the video (of doing it) or the image itself somewhere, so that I can take it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't do free work here.

Comment: Ok. You are right. It is Completely true

Answer (score 1):

That eagle head is available on clip art download sites. Get it from one of them. Pay if they want a price. Otherwise you will not get a high resolution version with transparent background.

Doing as suggested after you have purchased the high resolution version with transparent background should be no problem. I mean to make the layer duplicate with different color and shift it a bit to get the fake emboss effect. If it's a problem, then it's not at all clear what you are going to do with the image?

Using a clipart image as a business logo is not generally a fine idea and it can even be illegal if it's not allowed by the real copyright owner of the image.